# How to build EMOF models in IntelliJ and generate code from them?

Tags: intellij-idea, eclipse-emf, emf, ecore, mde

What is the best way to build models in IntelliJ, in the style of Eclipse [EMF](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) ?

Is there an equivalent of Eclipse [EMF](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) in IntelliJ ?
And is there something that adheres to standards such as EMOF in the same way that EMF Ecore is aligned to it ?

I found a plugin that seems to help with that [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7504-kevoree-modeling-framework-idea-plugin), but I am wondering if there are other/better options.

Answer (score -2):

Checkout the [Working with Diagrams](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-diagrams.html) docs.  JetBrains provides UML modeling and supports both forward and reverse engineering.  Although this is not EMF, it appears to be IntelliJ's equivalent in terms of functionality.

Note this feature is exclusive to the IJ Ultimate Edition.

Comment: The question was not on how to edit UML diagrams. The EMF (Eclipse modeling framework) is a powerful framework to create own models and implementations in Java. The implementations are tightly integrated into the Eclipse framework if desired. The question was: Is there a way to integrate the generated models (code, readers, writers, editors, etc.) tightly into IntelliJ?